# what is the difference between these two table

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have two tables written in two different ways, what is the difference?

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="table">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="eventStartTime">
        <mat-header-cell i18n *matHeaderCellDef>Event Start Time</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.eventStartTime | date}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
```

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
    </ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. Both are correct and valid, but in the Angular Material docs they tell to put `<table mat-table [dataSource]=dataSource>`

Answer (score 1):

1.Since you are using mat-elevation-z8 your table will look bit popped out. I don't know exact word but it will look sort of elevated from the page. Incase of normal class="table" you can define your own css or if you leave it as it is your table won't look elevated. But both of your code seem ok and should work.

2.If you go by angular material docs they tell you to use the second code. i.e `<table mat-table [dataSource]=dataSource>`. Similarly for `<th>` and `<td>` also.

Both of your code seem ok to me and should work just fine.